# How to list values in category and subcategory with foreach PHP

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

My clothes db like:

```
jeans | Bootcut

jeans | Straight

jeans | Slim

jacket| ..

shoes | ..
```

---

I try to list the products like in shops with following code:

```
<?php
    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT category FROM clothes ';
    $sqlSubcat = 'SELECT subcategory FROM clothes ';
    echo '<div>'    
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo ' <a>'.$row['category'].'</a>  ';      
        foreach ($conn->query($sqlSubcat) as $row) {
            echo '    <div >';
            echo '    <a>'.$row['subcategory'].'</a> ';
            echo '    </div>';              
        }           
    }
    echo  "</div>";
?>
```

---

**my expect:**

### [image]

### **but I get this result:**

[image]

---

**Only 1 subcategory will be listed instead of 3. Where is the mistake in the code?**

Answer (score 0):

I think shouldn't used execute sql query directly in foreach loop. You try this sample:

```
     $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT category FROM clothes ';
     $sqlSubcat = 'SELECT subcategory FROM clothes ';

     $tmp1 = $conn->query($sql);
     $tmp2 = $conn->query($sqlSubcat);

      echo '<div>';
      foreach ( $tmp1 as $row1) {

          echo ' <a>'.$row1['category'].'</a>  ';
          foreach ( $tmp2 as $row2) {
              echo '    <div >';
              echo '    <a>'.$row2['subcategory'].'</a> ';
              echo '    </div>';
          }
      }
      echo  "</div>";
```

?>